AD Group Vs Ldap Netgroup
i am trying to understand if there is any difference between AD group and LDAP netgroup
My understanding is ldap is used  to access the ldap server which is active directory in this case.
How is sudo access for a user providedto another say functional id using ldap group if its different from ad group

nisNetgroup (LDAP netgroup) is the objectClass with an OID of 1.3.6.1.1.1.2.8 used in LDAP for to describe a UNIX Netgroup.
AD Groups (in LDAP) Active Directory Groups is a collection of objects within LDAP but does not have the Netgroup attributes required to be used for UNIX Netgroup.
How is sudo access for a user provided to another say functional id using ldap group if its different from ad group?
There is a specific schema used for LDAP functionality of SUDO to store /etc/sudoers.

Don't confuse netgroups with LDAP groups. Netgroups are not a LDAP thing – they come from NIS/YP.
AD groups and LDAP groups are technically the same thing, because AD is LDAP – they're an LDAP entry that contains a list of (user or machine) accounts. But there are some semantic differences when it comes to non-AD (Unix style) LDAP directories; they often have two entirely different kinds of entries:

posixGroup for what AD calls a security group (which is applied to your processes upon login and becomes part of their 'process security token'),

groupOfNames for what AD calls a distribution group (which has to be queried "manually" by the program).


Often, only the latter kind – groupOfNames – is called a 'LDAP group', to distinguish it from posixGroup. In the context of SUDO it means that a 'LDAP group' requires sudo to directly query the LDAP server, while ordinary groups can be checked locally from the process token.
Finally, NIS netgroups are another kind of 'distribution' group (as opposed to regular "Unix groups" which are always of the 'security group' kind). They come from the NIS/YP directory system that was once popular before LDAP. They can also be stored in LDAP (and therefore in AD), but they specifically retain the (host,user) or (*,user) or (host,*) syntax for netgroup members (though sudo doesn't use the mixed kind).



Type
In NIS
In AD LDAP
In non-AD LDAP




Applies to process security token
group
security group
posixGroup


Needs a manual query by user DN
-
distribution group
groupOfNames


Needs a manual query by username
netgroup
nisNetgroup
nisNetgroup



